# If $\phi ^{-1}(X)$ is irreducible, and $X$ is contained in the image of $\phi$, show that $X$ is irreducible.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $\phi: V \to W$ is a polynomial map, and $X$ is an algebraic subset of $W$, show that $\phi ^{-1}(X)$ is an algebraic subset of $V$. If $\phi ^{-1}(X)$ is irreducible, and $X$ is contained in the image of $\phi$, show that $X$ is irreducible.

here $X$ being closed I think I can't write $X=X_1 \times \cdots \times X_m$ where $X_i=p_i(X)$ means projection of $X$ in the $i$th component then $\phi ^{-1}(X)= \cap T_i^{-1}(X_i)$. But also it will not be of any help.. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $X=V(I)$ implies that $\phi^{-1}(X)=V(J)$ where $J$ is the ideal of polynomial functions of $V$ generated by $P\circ \phi, P\in I$.

If $\phi^{-1}(X)$ irreducible and $X$ is contained in the image of $\phi$ implies that $k[V]/J\simeq k[W]/J$ so $k[W]/I$ is an integral domain if and only if $k[V]/J$ is an integral domain.

Comment: Will you please explain your 2nd part because $I(V(J))=\sqrt J$. how do you know this $J$ is prime?

Comment: I think it should be $\sqrt I$ and $\sqrt J$ rest are fine..

Comment: @Tsemo How did we get the isomorphism between the two coordinate rings? Can anyone please explain it.

Answer (score 2):

This is purely a question of topology. Let $Y = \phi^{-1}(X)$. Consider the restriction $\left.\phi\right|_Y : Y \to X$. Since $X$ lies in the image of $\phi$ , it follows that $\left.\phi\right|_Y$ is surjective. Thus, $X$ is the image of an irreducible set. We conclude that $X$ is irreducible.